# What CR-48 firmware lets you install Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, netbook, google-chrome-os, cr-48

This would be to remove Chrome OS and replace it with Ubuntu. Right now I am dual booting, but it uses CRos Kernel.

Luigi seems to no longer be around.

Comment: I thought the point of CR-48 was to NOT run a full version of linux, LOL

Comment: It is ish... but does not mean it can't.

Answer (score 0):

Using the tutorial found here: http://www.thechromesource.com/flashing-your-cr-48-bios/

Get into developer mode

use flashrom and back up EFI and write the H2O BIOS

Use a live thumb-drive of your linux version of choice

wipe the 16GB SSD completly and install Linux on to