# On a CR-48 how do I remove ChromeOS and install Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome-os, cr-48

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What CR-48 firmware lets you install Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/270989/what-cr-48-firmware-lets-you-install-linux)

I am assume I would flash a custom firmware and boot from a live usb. Then? Do I errase all the partitions?